# Customize the view of context menu in android?

Tags: android

hello guys here is the image of my context menu
but i don't know how i can customize its view ??

i created  context menu by using this code

```
  @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) 
    {//local=v;
                    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);      
                   info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
                   menu.add(Menu.NONE, v.getId(), 0, "Play");
                   menu.add(Menu.NONE, v.getId(), 0, "Queue song");                  
                   menu.add(Menu.NONE, v.getId(), 0, "Edit tags");
                   menu.add(Menu.NONE, v.getId(), 0, "Set as ringtone");
                   menu.add(Menu.NONE, v.getId(), 0, "View details");
                   menu.add(Menu.NONE, v.getId(), 0, "Delete");

    }
```

[image]

but i wan't my menu to look like the one below .............
 i wan't to know how i can change the color etc of the context menu??also the purple line that appear's,is that a  nine patch image???

[image]

Comment: Do you want to set the Header in your context menu ?

Comment: @GrIsHu yes and a lot of other things as well....like i have said i want to customize the view of it too

Answer (score 4):

You can use `AlertDialog` to implement any custom context menu. create custom style view by

```
AlertDialog.Builder.setCustomTitle(View customTitleView) & AlertDialog.Builder.setView(View view)
```

You can listen to the long press event, and popup this dialog.

Comment: How will you track the item position when clicked, if you have a listview in your AlertDialog?

Answer (score 2):

I am confuse with your question little bit , correct me if i am wrong,

**Case  1 :** You just want to set Title as second image you pasted. For that you have to just `setTitle()` like `menu.setHeaderTitle("Select Option");` ,
So, Whole code should be like this ,

```
   @Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) 
{//local=v;
                super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);      
               info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
               menu.setHeaderTitle("Select Option"); 
               menu.add(Menu.NONE, v.getId(), 0, "Play");
               menu.add(Menu.NONE, v.getId(), 0, "Queue song");                  
               menu.add(Menu.NONE, v.getId(), 0, "Edit tags");
               menu.add(Menu.NONE, v.getId(), 0, "Set as ringtone");
               menu.add(Menu.NONE, v.getId(), 0, "View details");
               menu.add(Menu.NONE, v.getId(), 0, "Delete");

}
```

**Case 2:** You are asking about some other Themes.In that case you should use other context menu theme.

**Case 3 :** You totally want to change UI , and want to make own UI. In that case you should have to [create custom dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341560/how-to-create-a-custom-dialog-box-in-android/13342157#13342157) and use as Context Menu.